# Insert aggregate jtl result in database after execution of jmeter script on slaves is completed

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins

I am running jmeter in master-slave mode and getting the result in jtl file.
I can get aggregate jtl result using command "java -jar CMDRunner.jar --tool Reporter --generate-csv test.csv \
  --input-jtl results.jtl --plugin-type ResponseTimesOverTime"
and then can write custom script to insert this data in the database.

Can all these activities happen in one jmeter script?

Answer (score 0):

You can add [tearDown Thread Group](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#tearDown_Thread_Group) containing:

- [OS Process Sampler](https://blazemeter.com/blog/how-run-external-commands-and-programs-locally-and-remotely-jmeter) - to execute this CMDRunner.jar
- [JDBC Request Sampler](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JDBC_Request) or [PostProcessor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JDBC_PostProcessor) to insert the file into the database.

You may have to add `jmeter.save.saveservice.autoflush=true` line to *user.properties* file of your JMeter installation as JMeter doesn't write results in the real time. Or add a [Timer](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#timers) to sleep for a while till results are written to .jtl file.

Comment: I tried running tearDown Thread Group, but it runs on all slaves (throwing error jtl not found) and not on the master (my jtl gets created on master and i want to process that) when the earlier thread has finished its execution